# Trying to remove auxiliary counter variable from recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) 15 (spoilers): 
[image]

I solved this problem by realizing that it was a sequence of [central binomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html). Another good way is through [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Nonetheless, it seemed so natural to do recursively, that I did it anyway.

Here's my solution:

```
public long getNumberOfPaths()
{
    getPaths(board[0][0]); //2D array of Positions
    return count; //instance member (long)
}

private void getPaths(Position p)
{   
    if (p.hasDown())
    {
        getPaths(p.getDown());
    }

    if (p.hasRight())
    {
        getPaths(p.getRight());
    }

    if ((p.getRow() == board.length - 1) && (p.getColumn() == board.length -1))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

NB: Size of board is: 1 + inputSize, so in this case it would be 21, since we have a 20x20 grid. This is because solving the above 2x2 problem is equivalent to solving the 3x3 problem, but going through the squares instead of traveling on their borders.

The logic of `getPaths(Position p)` is: go down for as long as you can, then go right for as long as you can. Once you hit the bottom right `Position`, add 1 to number of paths (`count`), go back to where you last stepped down and now instead of going down, go right instead (if you can't go right, backtrack again, etc). Repeat process.  Of course, the recursion itself is keeping track of all of this.  If it's not clear, or if anyone want to screw with working code, there are two, small, classes [here](https://github.com/steve-p-SO/SO_Question).  Adding a few print statements to `getPaths(Position p)` should make what's going on pretty obvious.

Anyway, this all works properly, my question is how to implement this without using `count`. Again, as I stated above, I know that there are better ways to solve this problem, that's not my issue. My issue is trying to get the same functionality as above, but without using an auxiliary variable. This would mean changing `getPaths(Position p)` from `void` to making it return a `long`. It may be a simple fix, but I'm just not seeing it right now. Thanks in advance.

Essentially I want the recursive calls them selves to keep track of the count, not any sort of actual counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work

```
private long getPaths(Position p) {
    return (p.hasDown() ? getPaths(p.getDown()) : 0) +
        (p.hasRight() ? getPaths(p.getRight()) : 0) +
        ((p.getRow() == board.length - 1) && (p.getColumn() == board.length -1) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: @Steve P. That's strange, I don't see where it would be prematurely terminating. Maybe one of my parentheses is incorrectly nested

Comment: @Steve P. Yeah, my parentheses were off at first

Answer (score 1):

Without using the auxiliary variable:

```
public long getNumberOfPaths()
{
    return getPaths(new Position(0,0)); //2D array of Positions
}

private long getPaths(Position p)
{  
    long result= 0;
    if (p.hasDown())
    {
        result+= getPaths(p.getDown());
    }

    if (p.hasRight())
    {
        result+= getPaths(p.getRight());
    }

    if ((p.getRow() == board.length - 1) && (p.getColumn() == board.length -1))
    {
        result+= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Try this then:

```
private long getPaths(Position p)
{ 
    return (p.hasDown() ? getPaths(p.getDown()) : 0) + 
                 (p.hasRight() ? getPaths(p.getRight()) : 0) + 
                 ((p.getRow() == board.length - 1) && 
                 (p.getColumn() == board.length -1) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change your method signature to keep count as a parameter:

```
private long getPaths(Position p, long count) {
    if (p.hasDown()) {
        getPaths(p.getDown(), count);
    }

    if (p.hasRight()) {
        getPaths(p.getRight(), count);
    }

    if ((p.getRow() == board.length - 1) && (p.getColumn() == board.length - 1)) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```